# Next JS 13+ вернуть статус документа 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, nextjs

Использую Next JS 14.
Есть некий API запрос на получение информации о товаре.
Если бэк возвращает пустоту (то есть товара не существует), нужно директить на 404 **со статусом документа 404**, но каждый раз статус документа становится 200. Немножко кода:

```
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

export default async function ReviewsPage({ params: { id } }: IParams) {
  const card = await getCard(id);
  if (!card.item) {
    return notFound();
  }
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <div className="container">
        <CardReviewsComponent card={card.item} />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Страница 404 отрисовывается, но статус документа 200, может кто встречался
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что возвращает notFound()? "Страница 404 отрисовывается, но статус документа 200...", если это специальная страница, то логично, что статус документа будет 200, ведь страница-то была найдена. Другими словами, Вы не можете вернуть документ со статусом 404.

Comment: у вас SSR или обычный SPA?

Comment: Использую SSR, в общем вопрос в том, чтобы проходил редирект со статусом документа 404

Comment: @XelaNimed, _Вы не можете вернуть документ со статусом 404_ - вообще может

Comment: ты уверен, что 200 возвращается в случае срабатывания `notFound()`?

Comment: Да, уверен, скриншот тому доказательство, я прошёл по урлу с notFound(), получил 200 статус ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, кто столкнется с такой же проблемой, у NextJS есть промежуточное ПО (middleware), который возвращает статус документа при наличии верно настроенных путей и условий. Получил 404 статус документа с помощью этого кусочка кода:

```
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    /* тут условия */
    return NextResponse.next({
      status: 404,
    });
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/card/"],
};
```